# datalist li style

Tags: visualforce

I cannot set the 'li' style anyone knows why?

I have this original code

```
<ul class="unCollapsableSideBarList">
    <li class="sideBarListLink"><a href="#">aaaaa</a></li>
    <li class="sideBarListLink"><a href="#">bbbbb</a></li>
</ul>
```

I made it dynamic and replaced it with:

```
<apex:dataList value="{!products}" var="product" styleClass="SideBarList">
     <apex:outputLink value="myPage?id={!product.Id}" styleClass="sideBarListSelected">{!product.Name}</apex:outputLink>
 </apex:dataList>
```

The 'ul' style is set as expected but the 'li' is not
This is what I see (the li has no class) in the page source (I removed the ids because they are very long):

```
<ul class="unCollapsableSideBarList">
    <li class="">
    <a href="PortfolioCatalogDetails?id=a00d0000008PJEkAAO" class="sideBarListLink sideBarListSelected_product">aaa</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How about declare a style (like in css) and associate with li rather than using the vf attribute http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_styling_custom.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apex:dataList` doesn't appear to have any attributes that let you control the `li` tags it renders.

**Alternative 1**

Use the `apex:repeat` tag to create the list instead. For example:

```
<ul class="sideBarList">
    <apex:repeat value="{!products}" var="product">
        <li class="sideBarListLink"><a href="#">aaaaa</a></li>
    </apex:repeat>
</ul>
```

**Alternative 2**

If you insist on using `apex:datalist`, you can still style the `li` tags with CSS as such:

```
.sidebarList li {
    // css for li
}
```

Comment: `<apex:repeat value="{!products}" var="product">
      <a href="google.com">aaaaa</a> </apex:repeat>` I'm getting the values double time.Don't know why.Can u help me in this

Comment: Let's see what your VF page markup looks like.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set the style of the `li` tag rendered by the `<apex:dataList />` component using native tag attributes, as you've seen.

In the style markup you can target the element using a parent/child declaration rather than targeting the li element itself.

Like so: `ul.unCollapsableSideBarList li { font-weight: bold; }`

Alternatively, you can use a repeat tag instead of the dataList to create the unordered list markup, which will allow you to render absolutely anything you'd like.

```
<ul class="unCollapsableSideBarList">
    <apex:repeat value="{!products}" var="product">
        <li class="sideBarListLink">
            <apex:outputLink value="myPage?id={!product.Id}">{!product.Name}</apex:outputLink>
        </li>
    </apex:repeat>
</ul>
```